# Convolve does not excecute

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, convolution

The following `Convolve` expression doesn't produce a result.

```
a = 0.1;
ImpulseResponse[t_] := 
  (1/(2.*Pi*10.*Sqrt[1 - a*a]))*Exp[-a*2*Pi*10*t]*Sin[2.*Pi*10.*Sqrt[1 - a*a]*t]
pulse[x_] := Cos[2*Pi*x]
Convolve[ImpulseResponse[t], pulse[t], t, x]
```

I am trying to figure out why and make it work, but I am not really successful at that.

Comment: My guess is because your impulse response is an exponential that goes to infinity as t goes to negative infinity. Notice in the docs that `Convolve` executes an integral from -infinity to infinity. You probably want to multiply the impulse response you've given by `HeavisideTheta[t]`.

Comment: @N.J.Evans You are absolutely right. `HeavisideTheta[t]´ does the job.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your impulse response function isn't defined over `{-∞, ∞}`. But if you extend it as required with `UnitStep`, you will get a result.

```
With[{a = 1/10},
  impulseResponse[t_] := 
    (1/(2*Pi*10*Sqrt[1 - a*a]))*Exp[-a*2*Pi*10*t]*Sin[2*Pi*10*Sqrt[1 - a*a]*t] *
      UnitStep[t]]
pulse[t_] := Cos[2*Pi*t]
Convolve[impulseResponse[t], pulse[t], t, x]
```

> `(3*Sqrt[11]*(99*Cos[2*Pi*x] + 2*Sin[2*Pi*x]))/(19610*Pi)`